# Can't pass awaitable to asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have observed that the `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` function does not accept general awaitable objects, and I do not understand the reason for this restriction. Observe

```python
import asyncio


async def native_coro():
    return


@asyncio.coroutine
def generator_based_coro():
    return


class Awaitable:
    def __await__(self):
        return asyncio.Future()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(native_coro(), loop)
asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(generator_based_coro(), loop)
asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(Awaitable(), loop)
```

Running this with Python 3.6.6 yields

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "awaitable.py", line 24, in <module>
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(Awaitable(), loop)
  File "~/.local/python3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/tasks.py", line 714, in run_coroutine_threadsafe
    raise TypeError('A coroutine object is required')
TypeError: A coroutine object is required
```

where line 24 is `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(Awaitable(), loop)`.

I know I can wrap my awaitable object in a coroutine defined like

```
awaitable = Awaitable()

async def wrapper():
    return await awaitable

asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(wrapper(), loop)
```

however my expectation was that the awaitable would be a valid argument directly to `run_coroutine_threadsafe`.

My questions are:

1. What is the reason for this restriction?
2. Is the `wrapper` function defined above the most conventional way to pass an awaitable to `run_coroutine_threadsafe` and other APIs that demand an `async def` or generator-defined coroutine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is the reason for this restriction?

Looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/98b976a2f82ba5f50cf6846338f644ca6c64f47d/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L821), the reason is certainly not technical. Since the code already invokes `ensure_future` (rather than, say, `create_task`), it would automatically work, and work correctly, on any awaitable object.

The reason for the restriction can be found on the tracker. The function was added in 2015 as a result of a [pull request](https://github.com/python/asyncio/pull/273). In the discussion on the related [bpo issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue25304) the submitter explicitly requests the function be renamed to `ensure_future_threadsafe` (in parallel to `ensure_future`) and accept any kind of awaitable, a position seconded by Yury Selivanov. However, Guido was [against](https://bugs.python.org/msg252270) the idea:

> I'm against that idea. I don't really see a great important future for this method either way: It's just a little bit of glue between the threaded and asyncio worlds, and people will learn how to use it by finding an example.
>
> [...]
>
> But honestly I *don't* want to encourage flipping back and forth between threads and event loops; I see it as a necessary evil. The name we currently have is fine from the POV of someone coding in the threaded world who wants to hand off something to the asyncio world.
>
> Why would someone in the threaded world have an asyncio.future that they need to wait for? That sounds like they're mixing up the two worlds -- or they should be writing asyncio code instead of threaded code.

There are other comments in a similar vein, but the above pretty much sums up the argument.

> Is the `wrapper` function defined above the most conventional way to pass an awaitable to `run_coroutine_threadsafe` and other APIs that demand an async def or generator-defined coroutine?

If you actually need a coroutine object, something like `wrapper` is certainly a straightforward and correct way to get one.

If the only reason you're creating the wrapper is to call `run_coroutine_threadsafe`, but you're not actually interested in the result or the `concurrent.futures.Future` returned by `run_coroutine_threadsafe`, you can avoid the wrapping by calling `call_soon_threadsafe` directly:

```
loop.call_soon_threadsafe(asyncio.ensure_future, awaitable)
```

Comment: Nicely put. To give an example why "someone in the threaded world would have an [awaitable] that they need to wait for", I am testing a websocket server and I have multiple [websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) clients executing concurrently with test steps executed using Robot Framework. Not having control over the execution context means I cannot make it all async. In my case I do care about the `concurrent.futures.Future`, but that use for `asyncio.ensure_future` will be handy elsewhere.

Comment: @ChrisHunt I hear you. IMO the functionality provided by `run_coroutine_threadsafe` (and `run_in_executor` in the other direction) is a fantastic glue between asyncio and the classic synchronous/threading code, very important for introducing asyncio to an existing code base. It's unfortunate that it's underrated, often being omitted from asyncio introductory materials. I understand that the intention was to encourage as much code as possible to be "native" coroutine-based code, but that cannot happen overnight, and until it does, there needs to be a convenient way for the two to interoperate.